# Property value set in WiX based on registry key value

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

I want to set the INSTALL_DE property value to 1 if registry entry HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\LocaleName has value `de-DE`.

I wrote the below code.

```
<Property Id="INSTALL_DE">
    <RegistrySearch
        Id="NetFramework20"
        Root="HKCU"
        Key="HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International"
        Name="LocaleName"
        Type="raw" />
</Property>

<SetProperty Id="INSTALL_DE" After="AppSearch" Value="1">
    <[CDATA[INSTALL_DE="de-DE"]]>
</SetProperty>
```

How do I correct it?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Was the answer given of any help?

Answer (score 5):

Following your sample code as close as possible, I see three problems:

1. double use of identfier (in this case `INSTALL_DE`)
2. wrong key name; do not prefix `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` to your search path, `Root="HKCU"` takes care of it
3. Missing "`!`", in `CDATA`

Write e.g.

```
<Property Id="LOCAL_NAME">
    <RegistrySearch Id="NetFramework20"
            Root="HKCU"
            Key="Control Panel\International"
            Name="LocaleName"
            Type="raw" />
</Property>

<SetProperty Id="INSTALL_DE" After="AppSearch" Value="1">
    <![CDATA[LOCAL_NAME="de-DE"]]>
</SetProperty>
```