# RegistrySearch in WiX is not returning true for a value that is in the registry

Tags: wix, wix3.8

I have the following commands in my WiX Bundle:

```
    <Variable Name="InstanceName" Value= "SQLExpress" />

    <util:RegistrySearch Id="SqlInstanceKeyFound" Root="HKLM"
        Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL"
        Value ="[InstanceName]" Result="exists" Variable="SqlInstanceKeyFound" />
```

I can see the [SQL Server Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Express) instance in Regedit on the machine, but my log file is reporting this back to me:

```
Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL'
Setting numeric variable 'SqlInstanceKeyFound' to value 0
Condition 'SqlInstanceKeyFound' evaluates to false.
```

Why is this not returning true when I can see the value in Regedit? To add a little more information, this is supposed to be a check for an SQL Express 2014 instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<util:RegistrySearch>` defaults to searching the 32-bit registry. To search the 64-bit registry, set `Win64="yes"`.

Comment: If I set the 64 flag does it search both or just the 64bit?

Comment: Just 64-bit so if you support both flavors of SQL, you'll need two util:RegistrySearches.

Answer (score -1):

I'm irritated because of your WiX syntax. Why are you prefixing `RegistrySearch` with a `util` namespace?

Also, I'm not able to find s.th. in the lines of `Result` and `Variable` in the [WiX documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/registrysearch.html)? Shouldn't the registry search be a child of a `Property` element?

Cf. the answer in *[Property value set in WiX based on registry key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25363679)* for an example.

Comment: I am using the Registry search out of util see http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/registrysearch.html

Comment: That's a search in a Bundle, not in an MSI file.